# UserDefaults between iOS and WatchOS not working

Tags: swift3, nsuserdefaults, watchkit

Here is the code, but for some reason I get `nil` when I read from Watch. Any idea what am I missing?

Writing in iOS Method

```
@IBAction func writeDefaults(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.testingGroups")!.set(true, forKey: "myKey")
}
```

Reading from WatchOS

```
@IBAction func readDefaults() {
    let readKey = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.testingGroups")!.bool(forKey: "myKey")
    print("Key Value:  \(readKey)")
}
```

I also tried the following when reading but nothing...

```
 let readKey = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.testingGroups")!.bool(forKey: "myKey")
```

### Apple Developer Site:

[image]

### WatchAppExtension:

[image]

### WatchApp:

[image]

### iOS Project:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Communication between watchKit and app using userDefaults has been removed.
It can be done using [watchConnectivity framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity)

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought that the watch connectivity frame work was for heavy data and that userdefaults was still active. Is there any notification from Apple where thy state that this was removed? Thanks

Comment: Yes it was removed in watchOS 2, as since watchOS 2 apps run on the watch and not the iPhone.

Comment: Ok, I will look into it. Thanks a lot.