# Is sharing UserDefaults between iOS and tvOS still possible?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, tvos

**Is sharing UserDefaults between iOS and tvOS still possible?**

In my Xcode project I use `UserDefaults` to share data between my iOS target and my tvOS target. I always receive nil values from my `UserDefaults` when I try to get data back from my tvOS app.

These are the steps I took to share data:

1: Add App Groups for both targets. Both targets use the same App Group ID:
**group.nl.mycompany.myappname**.

*I use the .nl domain but this should be fine since this also worked for my other projects.*

2: Confirm both targets have the same deployment target. *I tried using 10.0 and 11.0.*

3: Validate the myproject.entitlements that everything is set OK.

4: Validate that on developer.apple.com the App Group is enabled for my bundle identifier.

5: Both targets have the same bundle ID. I also tried using 2 different bundle identifiers.

6: The way I write to `UserDefaults` from my iOS app:

```
guard let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.nl.mycompany.myappname") else { return }
defaults.set("Apple", forKey: "username")
defaults.synchronize()
```

I confirm this works in my iOS app by getting the value like so:

```
guard let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.nl.mycompany.myappname") else { return nil }
defaults.synchronize()
let name = defaults.string(forKey: "username")
```

This indeed returns "Apple".

7: Opening my tvOS app and calling this code returns nil:

```
guard let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.nl.mycompany.myappname") else { return nil }
defaults.synchronize()
let name = defaults.string(forKey: "username")
```

Is it possible that `UserDefaults` sharing has been removed? Something similar happened to sharing `UserDefaults` between your phone and watch link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41052513/6414904). I also read that the maximum size of `UserDefaults` is [500kb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32781011/6414904) for the AppleTV but saving this simple string should be fine.

Comment: Where did you read that maximum size of `UserDefaults` is `500kb`? I guess there is no limit until there is enough space in your device.

Comment: @TheTiger Thank you for your reply. I found that on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32781011/6414904

Comment: Now may be correct after specifying for `tvOS`.

Comment: I read the forum answer, although that question is for `tvOS` but answer doesn't specify this. Apple guy clearly said that `NSUserDefaults is allowed, and supports up to 500KB of data.` I wondered!!

Comment: @TheTiger It indeed is allowed but it seems there's a limit on the size of data based on the answer.

Comment: [About Limit Another SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510123/is-there-any-limit-in-storing-values-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple clearly states in the [`UserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) documentation that

> With the exception of managed devices in educational institutions, a
>   user’s defaults are stored locally on a single device, and persisted
>   for backup and restore. To synchronize preferences and other data
>   across a user’s connected devices, use `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`
>   instead.

As it says, you should use iCloud-based [`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore) for synchronized data storage.

As for its (`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`) limits, the documentation says

> The total amount of space available in your app’s key-value store, for a given user, is 1 MB. There is a per-key value size limit of 1 MB, and a maximum of 1024 keys.

Comment: My bad I totally missed this from the documentation but this indeed solves the issue. Thank you!

Comment: `There is a per-key value size limit of 1 MB, and a maximum of 1024 keys.` Oh that is why few are saying that there is not limit so they might be considering multiple keys. Good to know!

Comment: @TheTiger please note that that's for `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` - not `UserDefaults` (which is not limited by space in theory)

Comment: Okay, but why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644622/can-i-use-nsuserdefaults-with-tvos/32781011#32781011) is for `UserDefaults` ?